# Facebook like button box opening outside window area

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have a facebook like button at the bottom of my website. When I click on it the "box" where I can input a comment goes outside my web-browser window and I can not scroll down or anything like that (see screenshot below - bottom of the image is bottom of the window). How can I fix this? (ie. make the box appearing above the button). tks

[image]

**HTML**

```
  <div id="social">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mydomain.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="106" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="msa">Tweet</a> 
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 96%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 30px 2%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#social {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 2%;
    color: #333;
}

.fb_iframe_widget, iframe.twitter-share-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.languageselector {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px; /* same height as #social div */
    line-height: 20px; /* same as line-height */
}
```

Comment: You can't position the comment box, it's solely in facebook's hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a nasty solution. And I don't think it's a legitimate one. But if it's that much important you can override facebook css. In your case something like this will do the trick.

```
.fb-like.fb_edge_widget_with_comment.fb_iframe_widget span iframe {

/* Now you can apply css here */
bottom:0!important;
}
```

If you want to enable send button you can use,

For the light color scheme:

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_send_button_form_widget.light.fb_iframe_widget {

/********css code here*******
*Ex:    
position: fixed!important;
bottom: 20px!important;
top: initial!important;
*/
}
```

For dark color scheme:

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_send_button_form_widget.dark.fb_iframe_widget {

/********css code here*******/

}
```

I'm saying it again, this is not a proper solution. So don't use it unless it's really important. And remember those classes can be changed and not suitable for every occasion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by removing the attribute

```
overflow:auto
```

from the parent element

Answer (score 0):

This is a common sort of problem with embedding the *Like* button inside fixed and absolutely positioned containers. In your case the simplest solution is to move the like button higher up in the page. You can't force the comment box to pop *up* instead of *down*.