# How to make the Facebook Comment box that appears after liking display above and not below

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'd like to make the Comment box that pops up under the Facebook (fbml) Like button when a user clicks it pop UP instead.

Currently it shows under the like button, and I want it to display above.

The page where I received the code is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

apparently there's no solution for this issue. Please refer to this SO answer: 
[Facebook like button box opening outside window area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022007/facebook-like-button-box-opening-outside-window-area)